# Thymeleaf: is it possible to assemble page with th:include, but disable text substitution for th:text values?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have never before heard of Thymeleaf. Now I have received a set of Thymeleaf templates. An HTML page is assembled from several of these files with `th:include`s and `th:replace`s. I wish it to happen, so I could see the page, but I don't wish to write Java code to run all this.

In other words, I just want `th:include`s and `th:replace`s to be processed, and `th:text` and other instructions ignored, so I could see prototype page assembled from templates.

Is it possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Thymeleaf is the view layer, you still need the Model/Controller to be able to drive the manipulation of it. Without java code to enact and to activate the relevant logic for th:include and th:replace you won't be able to manage this at this stage.